# SwiftUI animation freeze on first display

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I'm coding my first SwiftUI app and I want to create an animation on a text (to slowly show and hide this text). Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TrendLabel: View {
    let trendType: String
    
    @State private var animationAmount = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if(trendType != "aucune"){
                Label(trendType, systemImage: "arrow.down.right")
                    .foregroundColor(trendType == "hausse" ? .red : .green)
                    .opacity(2 - animationAmount)
                    .animation(
                        .easeOut(duration: 1).delay(1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
                        value: animationAmount
                    )
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            animationAmount = 1.6
        }
    }
}

struct TrendLabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TrendLabel(trendType: "hausse")
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work as my text is freeze with the minimum opacity value ([here is a screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrePS.png)).

Someone knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your animation.

1. To animate opacity, you need either a `Bool` value, or an expression that can evaluate to a `Bool` value. You then use a ternary to make the decision.
2. `.opacity()` values must be between 0 and 1.

Your code should be:

```
@State private var animate = false
@Binding var animationAmount: Double

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        if(trendType != "aucune"){
            Label(trendType, systemImage: "arrow.down.right")
                .foregroundColor(trendType == "hausse" ? .red : .green)
                .opacity(animate ? animationAmount : 1)
                .animation(
                    .easeOut(duration: 1).delay(1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
                    value: animate
                )
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            animationAmount = 0.4
            animate = true
        }
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help!

I just tried it but the label is freezed with the minimum opacity value when it appears. But once I restart the app the animation works well.

Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: Can you detail how you are trying it? Is this part of a larger app, or did you just try to run this view in its own app?

Comment: I am not sure if this is. your problem, but I updated it to address a problem that can occur when starting the animation from an `.onppear`. Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm having similar issues for a while now. I'm also using a delay, but it feels that we are missing some '`onNavigationEnd`' callback. In my case, animating the list will cause the App to freeze (some endless loop, can see the memory climbing) and eventually crash. It feels like `onAppear` should be called on similar state that `viewDidAppear` is called on `UIKit`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Yrb's answer, you can create a modifier:

```swift
struct DelayedAppear: ViewModifier {
    
    let delay: TimeInterval
    let callback: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                    callback()
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onAppear(after: TimeInterval, perform: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(DelayedAppear(delay: after, callback: perform))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
HStack {
 ...            
}
.onAppear(after: 0.5) {
    animationAmount = 0.4
    animate = true
}
```